# Elasticsearch - extract values from a flattened field inside a nested type using a runtime field script

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping, runtime

I have this mapping, a big document actually, a lot of fields excluded for brevity

```
{
    "items": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "costs": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "costs_samples": {
                            "type": "flattened"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`costs_samples` is a flattened field type huge collection of possible costs (sometimes more than 10k entries), based on some dynamic dimensions. Have to highlight that `costs_sample` cannot live outside `costs`, since at query time some `conditions` from `costs` should be composed with `should` or `match` clauses, like (`costs.country=this_value AND some_other costs_samples_condition`.
I would like to be able to extract and eventually inject a new field at `costs` level as a runtime field, and then use that field to sort, filter and aggregate.
Something like this

```
{
 "runtime_mappings": {
    "costs.selected_cost": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source":
         "for (def cost : doc['costs.costs_samples']) { if(cost.values!= null) {emit(Long.parseLong(cost.values.some_dynamic_identity_known_at_query_time.last))} }"
      }
    }
  },
    "query":{
        "nested": {
            "path": "costs",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "filter": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                             "costs.id": ["id-1","id-2"]
                             }   
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                              "costs.selected_cost": 10
                           } 
                        }
                
                    ]
                }
            
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": ["costs.selected_cost"]
}
```

The trouble is `selected_cost` it is not created / returned by ES. No error message.
Where did I do wrong? Documentation was not helpful.
Maybe worth mention that I've also tried with 2 different documents, like `items` and `costs` and then execute kind of a join operation, but the performance tests were really poor.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, there is no way to use a runtime field inside a nested field type.